# How to set SinglePlanningCalendar's initial selected calendar view in XML?

Tags: sapui5

I want to use the `sap.m.SinglePlanningCalender` association `selectedView` to set the default selected View when a user starts the app:

```xml
<SinglePlanningCalendar selectedView="workWeekView">
    <views>
        <SinglePlanningCalendarDayView id="dayView" key="DayView" title="{i18n>calendarTabMyDay}" />
        <SinglePlanningCalendarWorkWeekView id="workWeekView" key="WorkWeekView" title="{i18n>calendarTabMyWorkingWeek}" />
        <SinglePlanningCalendarWeekView id="weekView" key="WeekView" title="{i18n>calendarTabMyWeek}" />
        <SinglePlanningCalendarMonthView id="monthView" key="MonthView" title="{i18n>calendarTabMyMonth}" />
    </views>
    <!-- ... -->
</SinglePlanningCalendar>
```

However, I get the Message in console:

> 2022-10-26 11:15:16.235500 There is no such view. - Element sap.m.SinglePlanningCalendar#__component0---Calendar--planningCalendar

And the view is not selected.

During the debugging of `SinglePlanningCalendar.js` in `SinglePlanningCalendar.prototype.setSelectedView`, I noticed that the `SinglePlanningCalendarView` instances do not yet exist during the creation of the XML view .

Callstack:

> SinglePlanningCalendar.setSelectedView (SinglePlanningCalendar.js:878)
> ManagedObject.applySettings (ManagedObject.js?eval:1207)
> (anonym) (ManagedObject.js?eval:520)
> constructor (ManagedObject.js?eval:535)
> constructor (Element.js?eval:200)
> constructor (Control.js:181)
> fnClass (Metadata.js?eval:454)
> (anonym) (XMLTemplateProcessor.js:1644)

So in console `sap.ui.getCore().byId("__component0---Calendar--planningCalendar").getViews()` **at that time** returns an empty array and the method runs into an error.

After the complete rendering of the page, `sap.ui.getCore().byId("__component0---Calendar--planningCalendar").getViews()` returns the array of the `SinglePlanningCalendarViews` instances.

I know I can set the selected view in controller. However, I was wondering if there is a way to do it in the XML view.

Comment: This is definitly a bug in `sap.m.SinglePlanningCalendar`. Please create an issue at https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues

Comment: Were you able to create an issue in the OpenUI5 GitHub repo? Is the issue still reproducible if run with `id="https://sdk.openui5.org/nightly/resources/sap-ui-core.js"`?